# mod_rewrite of from example.com/ to example.com/home/ for certain user-agent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know it should be simple.   But always can't get it right.  With the following, I can redirect example.com/abc into example.com/home/abc but not example.com/ to example.com/home

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*Chrome.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ home/$1
```

How can I redirect the / as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect *everything* from `Chrome` to be under the `home/` subdirectory, then try the following, it will match anything or nothing, and append it after `home/`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*Chrome.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```